# Align two p tags in this way

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to align two p tags in this way in html and css? How? Thanks!

I tried with many css codes but I didn't find the solution! The problem is that the second line of "Text text etc" go under the date, but I want exactly this:

```
2014-2020   Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text
            Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text
            Text Text text
```

My last code:

```
<span><strong>2014-2020</strong></span>
<span style="text-indent: 40px">Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text
Text Text text</span>
```

Comment: you should be using two container divs on a column layout. So that the first column contains the date and the second the text. Search for flex display and you should come out with a two lines of code solution

Comment: Yes, possible. Just I do not see any `p` tags in your code

Comment: Two options: use the `float` property of the CSS or use grid functionality of Twitter Bootstrap, which does it. These are basic and you should read a little before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. You could look at floats, flexbox, or grid. Below, I've used CSS grid:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template: 'date content';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>12-24-2021</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display flex

```css
.container{

  display:flex;

}
.first{
width:20%
}
.second{
width:80%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<span class="first"><strong>2014-2020</strong></span>
<span class="second">Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text
Text Text text</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="75">2014-2020</td>
    <td>Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text
Text Text text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least seven different options for achieving that layout. `float+flow-root`, `flexbox`, `grid`, `inline-block + calc`, `table-cell` and `position:absolute` are six of them.

But I'll show you how to do it the way you were trying, with `text-indent`.

```css
body {
  margin-left: 100px;
  text-indent: -100px;
  tab-size:4;
}
span:nth-child(2)::before {
   content:'\09';
   white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<span><strong>2014-2020</strong></span>
<span>Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text Text Text text
Text Text text</span>
```